# python sympy (inequality OR relational) to (set OR interval)

Tags: python, set, sympy, inequality

How to I take the result from a (inequality / relational) object and make it into a (set / interval) object?

```
import sympy
import sympy.solvers
#import sympy.solvers.inequalities
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities 

x = sympy.Symbol('x')

ExampleInequalities1 = [[x**2 <= 1]]
ResultDomain1 = reduce_rational_inequalities(ExampleInequalities1, x)
print 'ResultDomain1', ResultDomain1
```

Gives me:

```
>>> And(-1 <= x, x <= 1)
```

The above result could be represented as:

```
>>> sympy.Interval(-1, 1)
```

Which is a Sympy Set Interval object. (which lets me use intersection, uniion, complement etc...).

How do I perform this transformation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `as_set` method:

```
>>> And(-1 <= x, x <= 1).as_set()
[-1, 1]
```

You can go back with `as_relational`

```
>>> Interval(-1, 1).as_relational(x)
(-1 <= x) & (x <= 1)
```

Comment: Works great for all cases except when I get a 'False' domain as my inequality result. I will make a special case to turn that into the EmptySet. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: As long as the inequality produces a SymPy object, you will get `S.false`, the SymPy false type, and `S.false.as_set()` gives `EmptySet()` as expected.